# Add Facebook tab for page for angular2 site

Tags: facebook, angular2-routing, facebook-page, facebook-tabs

I want to add tab in my business page for angular2 site. For that I follow that steps :-

```
 https://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/26330/how-to-create-custom-tabs-for-facebook-business-pages.aspx
```

when I click on that particular tab its showing "can not Post error message" and when I try to hit this link :-

```
 http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=12345678901234&next=https://www.aaa.com/#!/home
```

its remove home from this link and create that new link  :-
     [https://www.aaa.com/#*=*](https://www.aaa.com/#_=_)     and this link is not valid for my site.

Please tell me what I can do for angular2 site

Answer (score 0):

> its remove home from this link and create that new link :- `https://www.aaa.com/#=` and this link is not valid for my site.

You did not properly URL-encode the value - so the `#!/home` part belongs to the “outer” URL.

```
&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aaa.com%2F%23%21%2Fhome
```

is what your URL to call the Page Tab add dialog should end with.

Comment: you means I should do url encode firstly http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=12345677&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aaa.com%2F%23%21%2Fhome

Comment: I tried this but its showing :-This dialog has been passed a bad parameter.

API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: redirect_uri should represent a valid URL

Comment: The parameter name needs to be `redirect_uri` now, according to documentation, and not `next`.

Comment: please can you me example where I should add the parameter, Thank you

Comment: Replace `next` with `redirect_uri` …

Comment: I replaced and tried it but its showing same error message

Comment: Please check http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=12345678&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2www.jadwalak.com%2F%23%21%2Fhome

Comment: Now you have encoded the parameter value _twice_ … It needs to be `&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jadwalak.com%2F%23%21%2Fhome`

Comment: Now its showing this error message:-     API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178996/discussion-between-mangita-and-misorude).

Comment: It needs to be a URL that “belongs” to your app. It must at least match your app domain.